# Bluetooth and external speaker loosing audio data

Tags: settings, bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio

I'm experiencing a weird problem. When I connect my android phone (Android version 10) to a bluetooth speaker, for some MP3, the ones where there are pauses inside a track (for instance, for languages courses), the sound is not reproduced correctly.

Basically if a track is composed by sentenceA pause sentenceB
the very first beginning of sentenceB is lost. An example:

> Hello, how are you.........I'm fine and you?

In this case I can hear:

> Hello, how are you.........m fine and you?

Do you know how to fix this problem? I couldn't find any option in the phone.

Thank you

[edit] 
Android version 10
Kernel Version 4.14.113

Comment: Please always name the manufacturer and model name of all devices that are related to your question (phone, BT speakers). For Android devices also include the installed Android version.

Comment: sure thank you. Android version was already mentioned in the post